# VS Code "sort imports" command has disappeared as an option from the context manager

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Why can I no longer sort my imports in VS Code. I have changed zero settings and sometimes it just does not appear.

[image: No sort imports command available]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have recently changed this command to "Organize Imports"

Comment that says it is ready for October update

> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22147#issuecomment-1751173694

Comment that says the new command

> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22147#issuecomment-1767140242

Comment: You should accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.

Comment: @JialeDu you can't accept your own answer for 2 days

Comment: Please don't forget to come back to accept it two days later.

Comment: Supposedly, opening the command palette and typing "Organize imports" should do the trick – however, as of now (2023-12-21), that command is not available in my VSCode November update installation on Ubuntu :/

Comment: @user3389669 Yes it works for me on my mac, but a friend on PC running windows 11 does not have the "organize imports" command either.